# Programmatically Get a List of Wireless Access Points

Tags: javascript, api, node.js, geolocation

This is a general programming question although I would prefer a **Node.js**-geared solution.  Are there any JavaScript or .NET APIs for retrieving a list of wireless access points and their associated data (SSID, MAC address, etc.)?  I used **TamperData** to see what happens when you share your location with Firefox and got this request URL:

`https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/browserlocation/json?browser=firefox&sensor=true&wifi=mac:b8-c7-5d-07-6e-cf|ssid:TV2 Network|ss:-58&wifi=mac:00-13-10-8d-a7-32|ssid:LUBIN|ss:-61&wifi=mac:62-4c-fe-9c-08-18|ssid:airportthru|ss:-73&wifi=mac:00-24-93-0c-49-e0|ssid:Custom Gifts Memphis|ss:-87&wifi=mac:98-fc-11-69-35-46|ssid:linksys|ss:-87&wifi=mac:00-0f-cc-6d-ba-ac|ssid:3333|ss:-88&wifi=mac:40-b7-f3-5b-2c-60|ssid:ATT456|ss:-88&wifi=mac:00-c0-02-7d-5f-4e|ssid:iHub_0060350392e0|ss:-89&wifi=mac:00-24-b2-d5-df-9a|ssid:Memphis CPA|ss:-89&wifi=mac:06-02-6f-c3-06-27|ssid:3333|ss:-89&wifi=mac:00-27-0d-55-c3-20|ssid:custard|ss:-90&wifi=mac:a2-a1-15-0d-a8-68|ssid:SETUP|ss:-90&wifi=mac:00-0f-cc-76-5b-2c|ssid:3545 2340|ss:-92&wifi=mac:c0-3f-0e-6e-ac-34|ssid:patricia|ss:-92`

... which, when executed, returns a JSON object with exactly what I'm seeking: *latitude and longitude coordinates*.  The object for this example is:

`{
   "accuracy" : 49.0,
   "location" : {
      "lat" : 35.06993630,
      "lng" : -89.88568730
   },
   "status" : "OK"
}`

**CURIOUS:** how is the accuracy here represented?  I am fairly certain it's not a percentage because other requests with less access points listed return a higher integer.  For example, when removing every WAP except the first listed, I get an accuracy of `43000.0`.

I have been investigating the way the **Node** version of [prey](https://preyproject.com/) interacts with a similar Google service and it follows the same suit of passing a list of WAPs and their info.  I am trying to extract the bits of their code that accomplish this task but I am having trouble even getting the project to run properly.  If anyone has any information, I would greatly appreciate it, as I have a wonderful project in mind that makes use of such technology.  Thanks!

Comment: If the Google API follows the same rules as the [HTML5 Geolocation API](http://dev.w3.org/geo/api/spec-source.html#accuracy), which I would suspect it does, then accuracy is a value in meters at 95% confidence.

Answer (score 5):

This is truly only capable through Java applet or an application on the host computer. Chrome and other browsers achieve this by having an application on the users computer. This application forwards the data securely through an Https request and passes your mac id ans ssid to lets say Google. Here Google replies with its best guess on your location.

Comment: welcome to SO! congrats on the first bounty on the first day here!

Answer (score 1):

The [node_wifi_location](https://github.com/swdyh/node_wifi_location) npm package retrieves a list of available wireless access points from the local machine’s wireless card, and optionally passes them to the Google location API to retrieve the location of the machine. It relies on the wifi command-line utilities for the operating system, since each platform has its own APIs for accessing wifi hardware. There is no JavaScript API within any browser for retrieving the list of access points, only an API for retrieving location (the [HTML5 geolocation API](http://dev.w3.org/geo/api/spec-source.html)).

```js
var wifiLocation = require('wifi_location');

wifiLocation.wifiTowers(function (err, accessPoints) {
    // accessPoints contains an array of access point objects
    // with ssid, mac_address, signal_strength keys 
});

wifiLocation.location(function (err, location) {
    // location contains the location object from the Google Maps API
});
```

Comment: So google is relying on the user using Chrome as their browser. The browser is passing the data to the location api?

Comment: I’m not entirely sure what you are asking. Nothing except software running on the machine with the wifi card would be able to get information about nearby wifi networks. So, yes, the browser passes the list of nearby wifi to the Google servers, which then cross-check that against wifi data collected by Street View cars (and probably other sources) to determine your location.

Comment: I'm trying to get the ssid available to a PC ... I have poked around the chrome browser with no luck. I would settle for any kind of work around that gets this data. Note: this only has to work on my pc not looking for a pure web solution for I don't think it's possible

Comment: This question asked for a solution that used Node.js. node_wifi_location is a Node.js package that retrieves all available SSIDs from the system’s wifi interface. I do not understand what else you are looking for, but I don’t think this is the right place to ask.

Comment: @CSnover , I followed your guide. it works, but it list available WiFi list around NodeServer, not around Client. Is this true? I tested on my local, server and client both had same WiFi List