# How to display WI_FI List In Web Page using HTML5

Tags: javascript, html

Hi All is there any way to display the wi-fi list in web page using HTML5 code.
I am using this code but it is not supporting by any browser..

Comment: Do you mean a list of Wi-Fi access points?

Comment: It mean's all available network inside wi-fi range..

Comment: I am asking you about it. is there any possibility To access it.. and  show the list inside web page by HTML5 code.

Comment: Is this for a client side browser app or a server side app? Your question does not include enough information for me to know how you are attempting to do what you are. It's a very poor quality question.

Comment: Obviously it's a client site app..

Comment: No, it isn't obvious. It might have been an electron project, you might have been using node. There's nothing to show what you have or haven't tried or have investigated so it was up to me to consider a number of possible options. As a purely browser based project I'd say this isn't likely wouldn't be possible for security reasons.

Comment: For server side programming i know it is possible i did it. But client side i have confusion about it possibility..

Comment: @Ankit any news on this, is it possible?

Comment: Yes we need to create the Rest API and Front end we can display the wifi-list.

Answer (score -2):

Use HTML List to show list of items
http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_lists.asp

Comment: This is very generic. I want to display wi-fi list from wi-fi Access point. Is there any way to display this list.

Answer (score -2):

Think about it, what would you like to achieve with this and why should it be allowed to work?

In a `Client-Server` environment you would want to display the WiFi list of the access points near the `Client`, but that's none of your business. And I see no business case for why you would even want to present this information. The client can use the device he's using to get that list for himself, without needing your app.

If you read the WiFi list on the `Server` and push it to the `Client`, you would be pushing the nearby access points of the `Server`. Something that is meaningless to the `Client`. And none of *his* business ...

I suppose you could write code to display the WiFi list on a handheld device, but then you're reinventing the wheel, and I as a client wouldn't want you to store my WiFi range, so I wouldn't be using your app.

It's redundant and a serious privacy concern. What use case do you have that would justify this?

Comment: Client side  there is no support of browser. So i am getting confusion here. So i am thinking it is possible work by HTML5 code .

Comment: I'm trying to explain _why_ there will not be (or should be) any browser support for this.

Comment: Ok Thank's Spikee   for this.

Comment: @Spikee, while ignoring your impolite dialog, in IoT world and some devices with WiFi Direct capability you need to know the available WiFi networks. List them, filter them, even connect or disconnect them and it is completely ordinary. Also take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12285792/programmatically-get-a-list-of-wireless-access-points

Comment: @Spikee the question is if it's possible and how to do it, not a discussion if it will be good to have supported or not. -1 In addition there are tons of use case in IoT world as pointed out by Khalil